# Setting i2c slave address for Devantech digital compass

Tags: usb, i2c, slave, digital-compass

I am trying to interface with a Devantech digital compass found here -

http://www.acroname.com/robotics/parts/R117-COMPASS.html

I am using a i2c-usb converter to plug it into my laptop -

http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/usb_i2c_tech.htm

First of all, I do not know much about electrical engineering. I have a good idea of the bare basics, but after that I get lost.

I am trying to follow this tutorial -

https://xgoat.com/wp/2007/11/11/using-i2c-from-userspace-in-linux/

However I get stuck at the very beginning when I try to set the device address.

```
if( ioctl( fd, I2C_SLAVE, ADDRESS ) < 0 )
    {
            fprintf( stderr, "Failed to set slave address: %m\n" );
            return 2;
    }
```

returns "Failed to set slave address: Invalid argument"

I originally thought the address should be 0xC0 because a sentence in the manual for the compass reads "First send a start bit, the module address (0xC0)..." but that did not work.

Now I have a loop that just goes from 1 to 100 and tries each one for the address, but they all fail. The loop is -

```
for(int i=0x0;i<0x100;i++) {
    if( ioctl( fd, I2C_SLAVE, i ) < 0 )
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to set slave address for address %i: %m\n", i );
}
```

I'm not sure what else to try. Right now, I just want to set the address so I can start attempting to read and write. Since the converter is what is actually connected to the pc, should I be using the address for that? And if so, where can I find it on that link with the information for it? If someone has an idea of what I could try or what is wrong that would be great.

EDIT:

Okay I have the code like this now -

```
#define ADDRESS 0x55
int fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);

if (fd < 0) {
    printf("\n<0, %m", errno);
    return -1;
}

if( ioctl( fd, I2C_SLAVE, ADDRESS ) < 0 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to set slave address: %m\n" );
    return 2;
}

if( i2c_smbus_write_byte( fd, 0xAA ) < 0 )
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to write 0xAA to I2C device: %m\n" );
```

It will set the address, but it won't write anything. Whenever I try to write to it, I get -

```
Failed to write 0xAA to I2C device: No such device or address
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are your trying to send `0xAA` to the device ?
To my understanding this is not a register for it (for the `CMPS03`, the only command is register `15` and its usage is not common: change the `I2C` address, factory reset, ...).
And `0x55` seems definitively not the address of the device ... `0xC0` should be the write one.

Could be that `/dev/i2c-0` has not been created properly / is not correct?
How did you get `/dev/ic2-0` created ?